# How does apple define "user action"?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video

I am currently working on a web project and I need to start playing a video after a swipe event and I can not make this work. I am using the HTML5 video player and JS to detect the swipe event. I first tried with hammer.js which makes it easier to detect swipe events, but after struggling to get this working I started using plain js.

After some debugging, I noticed that the play method of the video HTMLElement returns a promise. When I call `video.play()` from my swipe handler this promise is always rejected with the following message:

> NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the
>   user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because
>   the user denied permission.

As this problem only exists in iOS I started reading the apple developer docs and noticed that many features are only available after an "explicit user action". For example:

> Important: The webkitEnterFullscreen() method can be invoked only in
>   response to a user action, such as clicking a button. You cannot
>   invoke webkitEnterFullscreen() in response to a load event, for
>   example.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html

The same applies for calling the play method from js. It will only work if it was invoked in response to a user action.

My question here is, how does apple define "user action"? Because apparently, swipe events are not user actions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if they have a strict definition but for video it is generally 'clicking' a play button.

This does make sense from one point of view - the thinking may be that swipes often are associated with dismissing something and hence not a good candidate to allow to start a video.

The reason for the sensitivity with video is usually to do with users accidentally running up large data bills on mobile connections.

This seems to be less of a concern these days - for example the latest versions of iOS now support inline video autoplay on iPhones, which was blocked in the past.